# Is there anything up with users asking a lot of questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is there anything up with users asking a lot of questions? What about questions that go unanswered?

Is this bad stackiquette?

Comment: A good question is a good question. It doesn't matter who it came from or how it came about. If, hypothetically, all of stackoverflow was an encyclopedia written by a single person, it would be no less useful for that fact.